# Shortening .write commands

Tags: python-3.6

I am learning from the book *Learn Python The Hard Way 3.6*, by Zed Shaw

There are a series of 6 target.write commands towards the bottom of the script and he wants me to simplify them into a single target.write command using strings formats and escapes. However, I am stuck.

Here is the original code:

```
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv 

print(f"We're going to erase {filename}")

print("If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C).")

print("If you do want that, hit RETURN.") 

input("?")

print("Opening the file...")

target = open(filename,'w')

print("Truncating the file. Goodbye!")

target.truncate() 

print("Now I'm going to ask you for three lines") 

line1 = input("line 1:") 

line2 = input("line 2:")

line3 = input("line 3:")

print("Im going to write these to the file.")

target.write(line1)

target.write("\n")

target.write(line2)

target.write("\n")

target.write(line3)

target.write("\n")

print("And finnaly, we close it")

target.close()
```

So far I have tried 
`target.write(line1),(line2),(line3)`

but this gives a logical error of only writing to one line not all three.

`target.write(line1) + (line2) + (line3)`

with this one I get error

```
'unsupported operand types for +: 'int' + 'str'

target.write(line1),\n,(line2)\n(line3),\n
```

with this one I get error:

```
unexpected character after line continuation character
(<string>,line 22)
```

I have been googling and searching here for answers but have not found anything. One person posted a very similar question except for Zed's 2.7 book. However I am reading Zed's 3.6 book so the answers were no help to me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you have and haven't covered so far in the book as I'm not familiar with it but one way to do what you want is to format the string first and then pass it to the write method like this:

```
target.write("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n".format(line1, line2, line3))
```

Comment: Thank's man, never thought about doing it that way, i do know formatting to an extent but still pretty new to python. I'll give that a shot. So basically you formatted the line's into strings & embedded the variables into the string?

Comment: No worries. What I've done is to set up a format string and then called the `format` method on it to substitute in the variables. Another way of doing it would be `target.write(f"{line1}\n{line2}\n{line3}\n")`.

Comment: Ah that makes complete sense! Thank you again i forgot you can format string's that don't print / need to format string's in order to get {line1} etc to display properly/input properly. Mucho Gracias again.